# How to create a dictionary from list without the repeating elements

Tags: python, logic

I need to create a dictionary of elements without the elements that shows more than once and i want to keep the starting index.
Example:

```py
a = ['a', 'b' 'a', 'c']

expected = {'b': 1, 'c': 3}
```

To solve the problem i tried this way:

```py
def unique_array(foo):
   correct, duplicates = {}, set()
   for value in foo:
       if index, value not in enumerate(correct):
          correct[value] = index
       else:
          duplicates.add(value)
   return {k: correct[k] for k in set(correct) - duplicates
```

There is a better and more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two imbricated loops, which makes the time complexity of your code O(n^2).

An O(n) solution could be:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c']

out = {}
for index, val in enumerate(a):
    if val not in out:
        out[val] = index
    else:
        out[val] = None

out = {item:val for item, val in out.items() if val is not None}



print(out)
# {'b': 1, 'c': 3}
```

We first create the output, marking the duplicates with the value `None` when we encounter them. 
At the end, we filter out the keys with `None` value. Both operations are O(n).

Comment: @Austin I think that enumerate() counts as an inner loop.

Comment: @Thierry Surely you else could be del out[val] and then remove the last line?

Comment: @quamrana No, because by doing so, you would lose the information that val was already seen twice, and it would be counted again as a single value if it appeared a third time.

Comment: Ok, I get it now.

Comment: Yes, it’s difficult to see, but ‘in enumerate ()’ must iterate over ‘correct’ each time through the outer loop.

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to use a `Counter` and two passes. (It's still O(n).)

```
>>> from collections import Counter 
>>> a = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c']                                                    
>>> counts = Counter(a)                                                         
>>> {k:idx for idx, k in enumerate(a) if counts[k] == 1}                        
{'b': 1, 'c': 3}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do this by using a single loop

```
alphabets = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c']
alphabetDict = {}
index = 0
for alphabet in alphabets:
    count = alphabets.count(alphabet)
    if count == 1:
        alphabetDict[alphabet] = index
        index += 1
    else:
        index += 1
        continue

print(alphabetDict)
```